# php dio_write give error in windows

Tags: php

i want to pass at commands using php  dio extension and at command in windows.
dio_open(); function working well but dio_write(); give an error.
i dont know reason here is my code..

error..

```
Warning: dio_write(): cannot write data to file descriptor 3: Bad file descriptor in C:\xampp\htdocs\dio.php on line 17
```

code

```
$fd = dio_open('COM8:', O_RDONLY);
if(!$fd)
{
echo "Connection not working";
}
else
{
//echo "Connection working";
//$result = dio_write($fd, 'aaaaa_bbbbb_ccccc_ddddd_',12 );
dio_write($fd, "AT\n");
      //dio_write($fd, "AT\r");
    //dio_write($fd, "AT+CMGF=1\r");
    //dio_write($fd, "AT+CMGL="ALL"\r");








}
```

Comment: Why do you open the stream `READONLY` and then try to _write_ to it?

Comment: i use O_WRONLY thank pont me write direction

Comment: You are welcome :-) Oh, and do yourself a favor: when starting programming, think about switching to a better operating system.